# Changing Visual States in a ContentDialog

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-cx, visualstatemanager

I am having trouble getting the `VisualStateManager` to switch states in a custom `ContentDialog`. I have included a self-contained example where the XAML page defines two rectangles with different colours and some visual states to adjust the visibility of the two rectangles. The idea is that when the button is pressed the rectangle that was previously invisible is now visible. However, what actually happens is that `VisualStateManager::GoToState()` returns false and no visual state change occurs.

Am I doing something obvious wrong here? I believe the `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>` element is in the correct place (being the child of the root element's child) but I'm still unable to get this scenario to work.

The XAML file:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="Test.MyContentDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    MaxWidth="750"
    MaxHeight="550"
    Background="Black">

    <Grid Width="500" Height="210" Margin="0,25,0,0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="BlueVisibleState">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="BlueRect.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Target="RedRect.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="RedVisibleState">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="BlueRect.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Target="RedRect.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Rectangle x:Name="BlueRect" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="RedRect" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" />

        <Button Content="Change Style" Width="500" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

And the code-behind:

```
namespace Test
{

MyContentDialog::MyContentDialog()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VisualStateManager::GoToState(this, BlueVisibleState->Name, false);
}

void MyContentDialog::Button_Click( Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e )
{
    VisualStateManager::GoToState(this, RedVisibleState->Name, true);
}

} // namespace Test
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a demo using your codes and reproduced the problem. It seems like the `VisualStateManager.GoToState` doesn't work with Content Dialog.

But it works well in a [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). So as a workaround, you can create a new user control and wrap it with your content dialog:

New user control xaml (RootDialogControl.xaml):

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="VisualStatesSampleCpp.RootDialogControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VisualStatesSampleCpp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="BlueVisibleState">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="BlueRect.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="RedRect.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="RedVisibleState">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="BlueRect.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="RedRect.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle x:Name="BlueRect" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="RedRect" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" />
        <Button Content="Change Style" Width="500" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind (RootDialog.xaml.cpp):

```
RootDialogControl::RootDialogControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VisualStateManager::GoToState(this, BlueVisibleState->Name, false);
}


void VisualStatesSampleCpp::RootDialogControl::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    VisualStateManager::GoToState(this, RedVisibleState->Name, false);
}
```

And wrap the user control in content dialog:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="VisualStatesSampleCpp.RootDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VisualStatesSampleCpp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TITLE"
    PrimaryButtonText="Button1"
    SecondaryButtonText="Button2"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">

<Grid Width="500" Height="210" Margin="0,25,0,0">
    <local:RootDialogControl/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Dear Elvis, thanks for the info! Do you know WHY GoToState doesn't work there? I checked and both classes inherit Control. Maybe only the ones that inherit UserControl work? Please elaborate.

Comment: It would seem that `VisualStates` only work within a `ControlTemplate` which explains this issue. See here for more: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2816